# AngularJS and JSON returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, json

Hi I have got a data in LocalStorage as JSON string:

```
[
     {"Date":"28/04/2016","Time":"08:00","Title":"Title 1"},
     {"Date":"28/04/2016","Time":"08:30","Title":"Title 2"}
]
```

And my **module.factory** looks like:

```
module.factory('$schedule', function() {
        var schedule = {};

        var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myAgenda'));

        schedule.items = [{
                title: result.Title,
                date: result.Date,
                time: result.Time           
        }];
        return schedule;
    });
```

When I am trying to get data it returns undefined. When I try to get a specific object like:

```
console.log(result[0].Title);
```

It works fine and shows only the first element. I guess I missing each definition but don't know how to do it. Please help me to get all results in my **schedule.items**.

And I am passing the result as items into:

```
module.controller('ScheduleController', function($scope, $schedule) {    
  $scope.items = $schedule.items; 
});
```

Many thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the data?

Comment: Is the format correct? `[{"Date":"28/04/2016","Time":"08:00","Title":"Title 1"},{"Date":"28/04/2016","Time":"08:30","Title":"Title 2"]` or are you missing a }?

Comment: Hi @LukaJacobowitz I am using the controller: module.controller('ScheduleController', function($scope, $schedule) {
          $scope.items = $schedule.items;
        });

Comment: You should iterate the array, where now you are not doing so, since you got undefined !

Comment: Hi @optimus can you please show me an example. I really don't know how to do it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @qqruza: late to the party! hope you sort it out already  from chris answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access fields in an array without mentioning wich array element you want to access. If you want to enumerate all agenda entries and add them to your array, it should look something like this:

```
module.factory('$schedule', function () {
    var schedule = [];

    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myAgenda'));

    result.forEach(function (date) {
        schedule.push({
            title: date.Title,
            date: date.Date,
            time: date.Time
        })
    })

    return schedule;
});
```

Comment: I have got an error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: If you look at the line of code "var schedule = {};" i changed it into "var schedule = [];" wich indicates an empty array instead of an empty object. That way you'll be able to use push!

Comment: I have done this change but still receive the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined pointing to this line: schedule.items.push({

Comment: My appolegies, schedule.push({ it has to be and not schedule.items.push({

Comment: Thank you @Chris but in my module.controller I am expecting: $scope.items = $schedule.items; so can use ng-repeat="item in items"

Comment: But you do not need to call $schedule.items in your controller. Just remove the items part and it will work. So you can do $scope.items = $schedule; and $scope.items will contain the array

Comment: Thanks a million @Chris

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.map` over array, also add missing `}` in your last element of array.

```
var schedule = [];
//assuming result returns an array.
schedule = result.map(function(value){
   return {
        title: value.Title,
        date: value.Date,
        time: value.Time
   };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with module.factory, but it looks like result is an array of objects and you're accessing it like a single object when creating schedule.items.

You might have to iterate over the array and create an item per object in result.